# optimizar consulta doctrine DQL

Tags: doctrine2

Estoy tratando de optimizar esta consulta, que tiene una subconsulta:

```
                $subQuery = $em
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('o')->distinct()
                    ->from('AppBundle:Report', 'o')
                    ->groupBy('o.project')
                    ->having('MIN(o.createdAt) between :start AND :end')
                ;

                $query = $em
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('p')
                    ->from ('AppBundle:Project', 'p')
                    ->leftjoin('project.reports', 'r')
                    ->andWhere(
                        $query->expr()->in('r', $subQuery->getDQL())
                )
                ->setParameter('start', $filters['start-report-date'])
                ->setParameter('end', $filters['end-report-date'])
                ;
```

Aunque funciona bien, la subconsulta devuelve casi 100000 registros, y el proceso se ralentiza bastante.

He probado con:

```
                $query = $em
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('p')
                    ->from ('AppBundle:Project', 'p')
                    ->leftjoin('project.reports', 'r')
                    ->groupBy('p.id')
                    ->having('MIN(o.createdAt) between :start AND :end')
                    ->setParameter('start', $filters['start-report-date'])
                    ->setParameter('end', $filters['end-report-date'])
                ;
```

Pero al ejecutarla doctrine devuelve error:

No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.

Revisando el log que genera el symfony, veo que "no result was found" es debido a una consulta anterior, que añade un count() al principio:

```
DEBUG - SELECT DISTINCT p0_.id AS id_0, 
                       p0_.created_at AS created_at_1 
        FROM project p0_ 
          LEFT JOIN rfq r1_ ON p0_.rfq_id = r1_.id 
          LEFT JOIN place p2_ ON p0_.place_id = p2_.id 
          LEFT JOIN customer c3_ ON p0_.customer_id = c3_.id 
          LEFT JOIN report r4_ ON p0_.id = r4_.project_id 
        WHERE p0_.deleted_at IS NULL 
          AND p0_.type IN ('tracking_project')
          AND p0_.type IN ('tracking_project') 
        HAVING MIN(r4_.created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ? 
        ORDER BY p0_.created_at DESC 
        LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 

DEBUG - SELECT count(DISTINCT p0_.id) AS sclr_0 
        FROM project p0_ 
          LEFT JOIN rfq r1_ ON p0_.rfq_id = r1_.id 
          LEFT JOIN place p2_ ON p0_.place_id = p2_.id 
          LEFT JOIN customer c3_ ON p0_.customer_id = c3_.id 
          LEFT JOIN report r4_ ON p0_.id = r4_.project_id 
        WHERE p0_.deleted_at IS NULL 
          AND p0_.type IN ('tracking_project') 
          AND p0_.type IN ('tracking_project') 
        HAVING MIN(r4_.created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ? 

CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException: "No result was found for query although at least one row was expected." at /home/angel/desarrollo/gpar/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SingleScalarHydrator.php line 43
```

creo que tengo el fallo en la forma del having y del groupBy, pero no veo como solucionarlo... :(

Comment: Y qué pasa si corres manualmente las querys que te pasa el DEBUG en tu BBDD? por lo que veo, a ambas les falta la cláusula GROUP BY

Comment: la primera consulta me devuelve los ids de la tabla project, de forma correcta (los que quiero). La segunda con el count, en cambio, da un error de malformed.  si quito el group_by, la consulta funciona y devuelve datos, pero no son correctos, ya que no se aplica primero a la subconsulta, sino a todo en general.  La verdad es que no veo manera de hacerla sin subconsulta...